# Rails - how to handle multiple associations the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I'm currently learning rails by working on a little personal project (best way to learn!) and I have some problems with models associations. After a day of searching I wasn't able to find answers to my questions.

I have 3 things to manage: posts (like in a blog), galleries and images.
What I want to do is :

- A post can have one (only one) image, like a main image, and one (only one) gallery.
- A gallery can have multiple images.
- An image can be the main image of multiple posts, and also be in multiples galleries.
- A gallery can be used by multiples posts.
- When something is removed, it doesn't break the app (for example, if I remove an image, if it's linked to a gallery or a post, the link is removed autmatically.)

**Edit**: I don't upload images when I create (or edit) a post or a gallery. Basically, when I create (or edit) a post or a gallery, I juste want to display all the images stored in the db and select which image I want to add in a gallery (or as a post's main_image.)

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to do it.

What I have now (and it works) is 3 models for each data (*Post*, *Gallery* and *Image*) and 3 models for join tables (*PostsGallery*, *PostsImage* and *GalleriesImage*.)

**models/post.rb**

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_images
  has_many :images, through: :posts_images
  has_many :posts_galleries
  has_many :galleries, through: :posts_galleries
```

**models/gallery.rb**

```rb
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :galleries_images
  has_many :images, through: :galleries_images
  has_many :posts_galleries
```

**models/image.rb**

```rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :galleries_images
  has_many :posts_images
```

And for the join tables:

**models/posts_gallery.rb**

```rb
class PostsGallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :gallery
```

**models/posts_image.rb**

```rb
class PostsImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :image
```

**models/galleries_image.rb**

```rb
class GalleriesImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :image
```

I wasn't able to create a *has_one* assiociation to link only one image to the *post* model, same with the galleries. I don't know where I failed, but I had errors. So I had to use some tricks in the code to store only one entry for the post main image, and for the post gallery. It's not great, but it works and I will do with that for the time being.

With the code I have in my controllers, when I remove an image, the entries in the join tables (*galleries_images* and *posts_images*) are removed too. Same when I remove a gallery, the entries in the *galleries_images* and *posts_galleries* tables are removed, etc.

Everything works like I want, but I don't know if this is a nice way to do it, and I'm still trying to find another way. I've looked at the polymorphic associations but I wasn't able to find an explanation on how to do it with my requirements.

If someone has an idea and can explain a (the?) good way of doing what I want to do, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks to anyone who read this post!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of joining models, please define your association like that:

**post.rb**

```
  has_one :main_image, class_name: Image, as :imagesable.
  belongs_to :gallery
```

**gallery.rb**

```
  has_many :images, as: imageable
```

**image.rb**  (Polymorphic)

```
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
```

To learn more about assocaition, please follow this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to change the associations but it don't works as planned.
Differents posts can't have the same main_image, and an image can't be the main_image of a post and at the same time an image of a gallery.
What is happening is everytime I update a post or a gallery, the field imagesable_id is changed. Because of that, I can't make an image the main_image of differents posts (and/or an image of a gallery.)
Do you think I still need a join model, or can it be done with your configuration?

Comment: Maybe I should have pointed out that I don't upload image when I create a gallery or a post.
I have a controller to upload images, which is independent from the others controllers. What I do when I create (or edit) a post or a gallery is displaying all images saved in the db, and with checkboxes I choose which image I want in my gallery (or as my post's main_image.)